# jquery как перезаписать данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

есть скрипт который по нажатию на одну из кнопок выводит данные на экран, но данные накладываются друг на друга по нажатию на кнопки, что использовать вместо **append** что бы их перезаписывать?

```
  success: function (response) {
                var len = response.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var title = response[i].title;
                    var price = response[i].price;
                       "<h1>" + title + "</h1>" +
                        "<p>" + price + "</p>" +
                        "</div>";
                    $(".goods-wrap").append(tr_str);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли Вы действительно хотите делать это внутри цикла.

```
success: function (response) {
  var tr_str = "<div>";
  var len = response.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var title = response[i].title;
    var price = response[i].price;
    tr_str += "<h1>" + title + "</h1>" +
              "<p>" + price + "</p>";
  }
  tr_str += "</div>";
  $(".goods-wrap").html(tr_str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сперва сделаем пустым блок, и уже после этого аппендим. Попробуйте:

```
$(".goods-wrap").empty().append(tr_str);
```